# How to log XHR request in Network Tab in Chrome even when dev tools is not opened?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

Chrome Console always keeps logs, no matter if the dev tools are opened or not. I want same for network tab.

Is it possible to log XHR requests in Chrome even when developer tools are not opened? If not, is it possible in other browsers?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting with this bounty?

Comment: An answer? Maybe in chrome or other browser.

Comment: Just a heads up, this sounds like a huge security concern to your computer by being able to see a log of all requests that happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a proxy outside of the browser such as [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for this. It's great, and the author of the tool even responds to questions about it on Stack Overflow!

https://www.telerik.com/fiddler

(I don't work for Fiddler, but it was there for us in the days before browsers had dev  tools)

Comment: Thanks...this is the best answer so far!...do you know how can I filter XHRs from a specific website?

Comment: This is totally possible and I do it all the time - Fiddler has all kinds of filtering options. There are other products that can do this outside of the browser too. Post a new question for this please and we shall answer, not really appropriate for comments i think (current question is targeted at Chrome's network tab so didnt seem right to put it here)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want some logging.  Chrome has a bunch of internal things it stores, you can check out chrome://chrome-urls/

Specifically chrome://net-export/
Also chrome://net-internals/#events may be of interest.  These things work across tabs, so imo it's nicer than having 20 chrome consoles open =p

https://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/providing-network-details

Comment: thanks for info. But it doesnt seem to be much useful. Just for a single xhr I got 100s of line of json

Comment: @dasfdsa well, it's json. Write some queries to filter it.  I think having more info is not a problem compared to having less... Use some lodash or underscore to filter your json.  
```{"params":{"load_flags":16384,"method":"GET","url":"https://s0.2mdn.net/8617621/1533737368131/scripts/polite-load.js"},"phase":1,"source":{"id":1936525,"type":1},"time":"509723024","type":97}```
The data is there.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to log XHR request in Network Tab in Chrome when developer tools are not opened. And I do not know which another browser supports it.

**Alternative solution**

But you could try the following extensions for Chrome:

1. **[ApiRequest.io Ajax Capture Debugging Tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apirequestio-ajax-capture/aeojbjinmmhjenohjehcidmappiodhjm)**. Capture API Requests and Responses in browser and share via a link. Makes collaborative debugging and issue solving easier.
2. **[Tamper Chrome (extension)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tamper-chrome-extension/hifhgpdkfodlpnlmlnmhchnkepplebkb)**. Allows the user to modify requests as they happen.
3. **[Live HTTP Headers](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/live-http-headers/eaiimeeggnhceafhencnejheejddlcpa)**. Monitor all HTTP/HTTPs traffic from your browser. Live HTTP Headers logs all HTTP traffic between your Chrome browser and the Internet.

And about "ApiRequest.io Ajax Capture Debugging Tool" you could read this developers article:

- **[How we captured AJAX requests from a website tab with a Chrome Extension](https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/apirequest/How-We-Captured-AJAX-Requests-with-a-Chrome-Extension/)**

Some of this extensions you could find for another browsers too.